# ArrayList cannot be set to model class

Tags: android, json, getter-setter

I am new to android.I have a `JSONArray` containing images and other attributes.I am trying to set it into the model class.

```
MenuContent singleItem = new MenuContent();
singleItem.setContent(mContentJsonObject.getString(AppConstants.APIKeys.CONTENT));
singleItem.setContentId(mContentJsonObject.getString(AppConstants.APIKeys.PARAGRAPH_ID));
singleItem.setChapterId(mContentJsonObject.getString(AppConstants.APIKeys.CHAPTER_ID));
singleItem.setClassId(getSharedPreference(AppConstants.APIKeys.CLASS_ID));
singleItem.setLanguageId(getSharedPreference(AppConstants.APIKeys.LANGUAGE_ID));
JSONArray mGalleryimages = mContentJsonObject.getJSONArray(AppConstants.APIKeys.PARAGRAPH_GALLERY_IMAGES);
for (int k = 0; k < mGalleryimages.length(); k++) {
    JSONObject mGallerycontent=mGalleryimages.getJSONObject(k);
    ImageGallery imageGallery = new ImageGallery();
    imageGallery.setImageId(String.valueOf(k));
    imageGallery.setImagePath(mGallerycontent.getString(AppConstants.APIKeys.PARAGRAPH_GALLERY_CONTENT));
    array_image.add(imageGallery);

}
singleItem.setImageGallery(array_image);
singleItem.save();
mParagraphsList.add(singleItem);
```

The problem is I can set all attributes except galleryimages array to the model class.But setImageGallery only is not working.I am getting null there when debugging it.This is MenuContent model class snippet

```
ArrayList <ImageGallery> imageGallery;
public ArrayList<ImageGallery> getImageGallery() {
    return imageGallery;
}

public void setImageGallery(ArrayList<ImageGallery> imageGallery) {
    this.imageGallery = imageGallery;
}
```

`ImageGallery` model class snippet

```
public void setImagePath(String imagePath) {
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
}
public String getImagePath() {
    return imagePath;
}
```

Can anyone tell me whats the problem?Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is **`array_image`**

Comment: ArrayList<ImageGallery> array_image;

Comment: Where did you initialize array_image?

Comment: @user9733846 can share exact error with question

Comment: Did you initialize? 
array_image  = new ArrayList<ImageGallery>();

Comment: yes,I had initialised

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod  I'm trying to get the arraylist content in recyclerview adpter.AppConstants.mMenuContentGallery=mParagraphsList.get(position-1);But only imagegallery is null.Other attributes are getting

Comment: @Jack above this  for (int k = 0; k < mGalleryimages.length(); k++)

Answer (score 0):

This code can be converted to 2 lines with well known [Google Gson Library](https://github.com/google/gson)

Have a glance at this.

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<MenuContent>>() {}.getType();
List<MenuContent> yourList = new Gson().fromJson(yourJson, listType);
```

**You dont have to write a long code with parsing with keys.**